# Rewrite URL on location change

Tags: javascript, jquery, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a way to rewrite URL of the location when the user want's to change page. So, let's say you have something like this:

```
<body>
  <a href="http://example.com" />
</body>
```

Is there a way I can catch URL changing moment, and actually modify that URL before location is changed, for example I would like to change href into relative link like `\http://example.com` and redirect page actually there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to trap the link and then modify it then yes, that's quite simple...

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stops the link doing its default thing
    window.location.href = "something/" + $(this).attr("href");
});
```

You obviously need to modify the line that changes the location, so that it modifies the href value however you need.  I'd also recommend giving the links a class and selecting them with that, as the above code will affect every link on the page.

Finally, this will need to run after the DOM is loaded, so either wrap it in a `document.ready` handler of your choice, or put it in a script at the bottom of the body.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I actually need to detect whenever document.location is changed, that includes not only <a> element, but also manual javascript. Handler for onbeforeunload event will detect location change, but I don't know how to get URL where it is supposed to go, do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: In that case, no.  I don't know of any way (with Javascript) to change the destination URL without a confirmation box every time (using onbeforeunload).

Comment: Seems like can't be done. Thank you anyway, this code will also help me.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help :)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zander_pope/akvm28tt/)

You can work from here. Also you will need urlrewrite in htaccess for this to work properly.

```
$(function () {
    $('.buttonn').on('click', function (e) {
        var seperator = (window.location.href.indexOf("?") === -1) ? "?" : "&";
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("s1") === -1 && window.location.href.indexOf("s2") != -1) {
            window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/&?s2=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "&s1=s1");
        } else if (window.location.href.indexOf("s1") != -1) {
            window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/&?s1=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "&s1=s1");
        } else {

            window.location.href = window.location.href + seperator + "s1=s1";
        }
    });

});

$(function () {
    $('.buttono').on('click', function (e) {
        var seperator = (window.location.href.indexOf("?") === -1) ? "?" : "&";
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("s2") === -1 && window.location.href.indexOf("s1") != -1) {
            window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/&?s1=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "&s2=s2");
        } else if (window.location.href.indexOf("s2") != -1) {
            window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/&?s2=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "&s2=s2");
        } else {
            window.location.href = window.location.href + seperator + "s2=s2";
        }
    });
});
```